# WordPress отправляет запрос на сайт gidvolos.ru

Tags: wordpress, seo

Сайт WordPress отправляет запрос на какой-то подозрительный "gidvolos.ru"

Этот сайт недоступен из-за чего запрос выполняется 20 секунд и задерживает загрузку сайта.

В консоли Chrome показывается такое вот сообщение:

```
gidvolos.ru/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/stat.php?s=nbnou Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Все подозрения на Yoast SEO. После Нового Года он обновился до 3.0.4. Еще WordPress обновился до 4.3.2

Откатил Yoast SEO до 3.0 - не помогло.
Попробовал отключить Yoast SEO - не помогло.

Comment: грепнуть "gidvolos.ru" по всем исходникам не пробовали?

Comment: пробовал - нету. Даже в исходном коде страницы нету.

Comment: Ссылку на свой сайт скинуть можете? Просто сеансы "телепатии" иначе очень долго продолжатся будут.

Comment: http://jam.com.ua/

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `jam.com.ua/wp-content/themes/jam/js/bootstrap-sprockets.js?ver=4.3.2`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Удаление этого файла из загружаемых скриптов помогло!